# Windows 10 technical preview restarts every few hours

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10-preview

I have recently installed a preview build of Windows 10.

> Windows Technical Preview
>   Evaluation copy. Build 9841

Unfortunately, now it begins to restart automatically every couple hours after showing me this message multiple times:

[image]

The automatic solution is to install a new build of Windows. But I really don't want to spend time reinstalling a lot of programs I have recently installed.

What I have tried to do is to prevent the OS from installing updates automatically but I have failed to do that.

```
PC settings 
-> Update and recovery 
-> Windows update 
-> choose how updates get installed 
-> Important updates
```

But I got this red message preventing me from changing `Important updates` from `Install updates automatically (recommended)` to `Never check for updates (not recommended)`:

[image]

How can I prevent Windows 10 Preview from restarting without asking for permissions?

Comment: [Here's how we did it for Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/490993/is-there-anyway-to-stop-windows-8-from-restarting-for-an-update/491004#491004). If it still works, feel free to edit that question/answer to keep it relevant.

Comment: Windows 10 installs the updates whether you like it or not. You need to get used to it.

Comment: What's your question.  You need to either install the update or reinstall Windows 10 your choice.  Your using a preview version of Windows and your right to that build has expired in the future once RTM hits we might be able to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this behavior is by design.  Windows 10 is pre-release software and therefore should only be used for testing and evaluation purposes.  Microsoft deliberately made it do this to prevent people from using it in a production environment.  There is no way to change the auto-restart behavior.

As for the Windows Updates issue, you may be able to use the solution from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/490993/is-there-anyway-to-stop-windows-8-from-restarting-for-an-update/491004#491004) (credit to @Lois for the link).  In short, you might be able to disable automatic updates by editing the local group policy of the machine.

Answer (score 5):

You get this message because the Build 9841 expired.

[image]

Windows builds that [expire do a bugcheck (BSOD) every 2 hours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [Microsoft released an update to expand the usage until october 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46447).

This is listed for the Server, but also works for the 64Bit Client.

Also upgrading to a new build, doesn't remove your tools, they are still installed. So upgrade to a newer build (10041 or 10049), [because Build 9841 will no longer boot after 2015-04-30](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/expiration-dates-for-windows-10-technical-preview/b979fd2b-f8fc-4e6b-a023-f018a0a44127) if you haven't applied the patch or use the 32Bit version.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When you installed technical preview iso you should have recieved a activation key. I installed the enterprise insider preview & recieved a activation key & it states in system that windows is activated with build 10074. In the insider programs with microsoft if joined there is a paragraph on how to find your activation key via command prompt it maybe helpful to find activation key and activate windows which should prevent your pc from restarting every 2 hours.

Comment: This answer does not really explain the behavior described by the author.  The answer also does not explain what the solution is if any.  We expect more substance and technical information from answers here at Superuser.