# How to stop Windows 10 from restarting computer on its own

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

You used to be able to [stop windows from restarting on its own](http://lifehacker.com/prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-restarting-your-p-1723647582). There was a big windows update a few days ago which appears to have disabled this option. Now my computer is restarting on its own to finish installing automatic updates. How can I stop this?

edit: the instructions in the "duplicate" threads do not work.

Comment: Schedule the restart time in a period of time where it will be acceptable for your system to reboot.  If that isn't acceptable use WSUS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: Better duplicate: [How to prevent Windows 10 from restarting the computer after installing updates](http://superuser.com/questions/1110265/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-restarting-the-computer-after-installing-updates)

Comment: The instructions in those threads do not work. "Windows cannot find gpedit.msc"

Comment: Looks like WSUS is for not applicable for Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/how-to-set-an-ethernet-connection-as-metered-to/ecdaca08-d413-4a6a-9e33-b4afb337fc18?auth=1), **if Windows thinks your internet connection is metered, it will not download updates automatically** - it will instead prompt you to download them (hence giving you the freedom to choose when you want your computer to reboot).

I modified registry to make Windows think my internet connection is metered.

**Warning: You can break stuff by modifying registry. I can't guarantee this works. If you don't know what you're doing, don't do it.**

- Step 1: [Create a backup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) in case you break something.
- Step 2: Open regedit (press the windows button, type "regedit", click the icon)
- Step 3: Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost`
- Step 4: Give yourself permissions to change the registry values in that folder. Right click on `DefaultMediaCost`, click `Permissions`, click `Advanced` and at the top click `Change` (owner). Add your username as the owner. Check that you have `Full Control` in the Permission entries list now.
- Step 5: Look at the different internet connection types listed in the folder (`3G`, `4G`, `Ethernet`, `WiFi` and `Default`). Value 2 indicates metered connection, value 1 indicates unmetered. Change everything to value 2.